# Save canvas to jpeg while canvas is not visible

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am programmatically drawing to a canvas using data entered by the user. Once all of the data is entered, the user can flip through the images and they will be drawn to the canvas. The user has the option to save all of the images(could be several hundred). I use a runnable that runs on the UI thread that will draw and save  each image(since you can't draw to a canvas from an AsyncTask). This works, but the problem I am having is if while the saving is going on, the user turns off the screen or minimizes the app. This causes the jpegs to just be black. I would like the saving to be something that could run in the background and still work.

Code used to draw to canvas and save image:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Bitmap bitmap;
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);

    // draw everything here

    OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(imageName + ".jpg");
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    stream.close();
}
```

So, is there a way for images to be drawn and saved to a file in the background while the canvas is not visible? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
I think you can use this:

signLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); //signLayout is layout that contains image you want to save
    // Save image from layout
    String path = "sdcard0/test/test.jpg"; //file path you want to save
    gestureSign.save(signLayout, path);
```

SAVE METHOD

```
//Save to path
public void save(View v, String SavePath) 
{
    if(mBitmap == null)
    {
        mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (layoutSign.getWidth(), layoutSign.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);;
    }
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(SavePath);
        v.draw(canvas); //Lay toan bo layout
        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, mFileOutStream); 
        mFileOutStream.flush();
        mFileOutStream.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    { 
        Log.v("log_tag", e.toString()); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is `gestureSign` (I know it's a typo, but a beginner won't).  You should also add some explanation.  Just copying and pasting some code is not an answer.

Comment: Even though this didn't have much of an explanation, it works fine and helped solved my issue. I removed the saving code from my onDraw method and moved everything to the run method of my Runnable. I can now draw and save all of my images in the background. Thank you!